# React native - Error with Google mobile ads

Tags: react-native, admob, react-native-google-mobile-ads

I am build a mobile app with react native

```
"react-native": "^0.71.1",
"react-native-google-mobile-ads": "^9.1.1"
```

Without google-mobile-ads, app is working okay. But with this module, I get this error

```
023-02-07 23:05:06.067 xcodebuild[92292:1835009] [MT] IDEFileReferenceDebug: [Load] <IDESwiftPackageCore.IDESwiftPackageSpecialFolderFileReference, 0x7fa23ae8f960: name:Docs.docc path:group:Docs.docc> Failed to load container at path: /Users/sangnlee/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/aaa-csqwegbowuhmbrehpztorwqemvkb/SourcePackages/checkouts/swift-protobuf/Sources/protoc-gen-swift/Docs.docc, Error: Error Domain=com.apple.dt.IDEContainerErrorDomain Code=6 "Cannot open "Docs.docc" as a "Swift Package Folder" because it is already open as a "Folder"." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Cannot open "Docs.docc" as a "Swift Package Folder" because it is already open as a "Folder".}
** BUILD FAILED **

The following build commands failed:
        Ld /Users/aaa/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/aaa-csqwegbowuhmbrehpztorwqemvkb/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/aaa.app/aaa normal (in target 'aaa' from project 'aaa')
(1 failure)
```

Anyone knows how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps:

```
1- You have to use the original ad id in the app.json file
2- If you are using expo then you have to include this

 "react-native-google-mobile-ads": {
    "android_app_id": "xxxx",
    "ios_app_id": "xxxxx"
  }
```

after the expo object

if this is not working feel free to comment here. I will try to response ASAP.